How to get user Id in Jhipster 8.4.0 (account.model) dont show id in class but show in console
Im using Jhipster 8.4.0 in my angular project
I can't get the id of my user logged into the account to do a search using this id.
Using:
  ngOnInit() {
    this.primengConfig.ripple = true;
    this.accountService.getAuthenticationState().subscribe(account => {
      this.accountState = account
      console.log('id data: ', account );
    });

I get the account information with all values:
id data:  
{id: 1, login: 'admin', firstName: 'Administrator', lastName: 'Administrator', email: 'admin@localhost', …}
activated
: 
true
authorities
: 
['ROLE_ADMIN']
createdBy
: 
"system"
createdDate
: 
null
email
: 
"admin@localhost"
firstName
: 
"Administrator"
id
: 
1
imageUrl
: 
""
langKey
: 
"pt-br"
lastModifiedBy
: 
"system"
lastModifiedDate
: 
null
lastName
: 
"Administrator"
login
: 
"admin"

I tried to map the return, but although it is clear in the console, the id does not appear free to access and I always receive the response that the id property does not exist.
As the model does not accept direct inclusion, I don't know what to do.
Remembering that I need to retrieve the id in my .ts code and not in .java.
How can I then, in my .ts component, retrieve the user id logged into the session in this new version of Jhipster 8.4.0?

It looks like this will work:
console.log('id: ', account.id);


hello Mark, this action dont work, this was my first attempt,I  solved it like this: first, create one interface with all attributes of account see on console, after, I used a "parse" from the account for the interface ... '    ````  this.accountParsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.accountState));
console.log(this.accountParsed?.id);```'. now it works, as I said before, the id attribute was displayed in the console but completely inaccessible, "account.id" didn't work, that's why I found it strange, other ways didn't either, but the one I explained worked and serves to help others
